# vscode display too much function paramters

Tags: clangd, grpc-c++

I don't know if this is a vscode bug or an extension bug.
And I didn't find how to disable it.

If anyone can see this picture, please help me.

Thanks!

For example:
The prototype for a function is:

```
static inline struct file *get_file(struct file *f);
```

a normal function display is like this:

```
file = get_file(vma->vm_file);
```

or

```
file = get_file(f:vma->vm_file);
```

But when it is abnormal, it displays like this:

```
file = get_file(f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:vma->vm_file);
```

I don't know how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD4rf.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have  write as text too. It displays get_file(f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f:vma->vm_file);   The many f: is abnormal.

Comment: What clangd version are you using? If clangd 13 and earlier, this is a known issue that's been [fixed](https://reviews.llvm.org/D110051).

Comment: Yes, it's a clangd issue. The version is /opt/clangd_14.0.3/bin/clangd, seems 14.0.3 have this issue. When I change to use "/usr/bin/clangd-12" this issue is disappeared.

Comment: My configuration is:
     "clangd.arguments": [
        "--background-index",
        "--header-insertion=never",
        "--limit-results=0",
        "--compile-commands-dir=${workspaceFolder}/out",
        "--completion-style=detailed",
        "--enable-config",
        "-log=info"
        ],